# Grabbing data from three locations on a worksheet and putting it into a new sheet as a report

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba code that grabs all the worksheets which are timesheets and puts them into one worksheet stacked on top of each other. I need another code that grabs three things which is the name, hours, percentage and the first name starts at cell "B6" and the hours are at cell "O47" and the percentage is at "O48". The next employees information for name, hours, percentage is exactly 100 rows below so the next employees info would be at "B106", "O147", "O148". I need a code to loop through the worksheet call it Sheet1 and grab all the employees until the code recognizes that the cell is blank and that is the end of the list.

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    For Counter = 0 To 40
    With ActiveCell
    .Offset(Counter, 0) = "="

    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[4]C[1]"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[45]C[13]*Sheet1!R[46]C[13]/100"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[46]C[12]"


    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[103]C[1]"
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[144]C[13]*Sheet1!R[145]C[13]/100"
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R[145]C[12]"

End Sub
```

okay so instead of having to repeat the 6 lines about 30 times is there an efficient way of doing it? the difference in locations are only the rows and its 99 (i.e you can see the row jump from 4 to 103. I tried using counter but got confused.

FINAL SOLUTION THANKS MIKE

```
Sub Macro1()
a = 1
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 6 To lastrow Step 100
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(a, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(a, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 41, 15)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(a, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 42, 15)
a = a + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: is that better? i included my code. I didn't know  how the site works apologize first time  user here

Comment: Much better, thanks for adding it :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is first look for the last row of information in column O by using the code:

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(rows.count,15).end(xlup).row
```

With this, you can then loop through the rows with the information:

```
for i = 6 to lastrow step 100
     ' grab the name in worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i,2) 
     ' grab the hours in worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i+41,15)
     ' and grab the percentage in worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i+42,15)
     ' saving these in the cells you wish
next i
```

By determining the last row first, you will be assured that as you go through the loop you will end at the last row that contains any information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks appreciate it a lot. Is this what you mean by grab the name? Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = "=Sheet1!R[4]C[1]" @mike

Comment: Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2) will contain the name from Sheet1, so you will want to save it in the cell on your other sheet.  In this case, something like Worksheets("Other Sheet").cells(1,4) = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(i,2).  As a side note, you will notice that in the cells() statement, cells has the format of row and column.  So it will be Cells(row,column).

Comment: I've added the code to the question above to the bottom. The code seems to be running forever and crashing my excel. @mike

Comment: Your code is going to run forever because of the do loop you have added.  You won't need it for this, it appears, but if you do for some other reason, you'll need to put a test within the do loop to give it a way to exit the loop.

Comment: I removed the loop, I thought I had to loop so it can run again. Now that I run the code above. Its removing the data in the source spread sheet like the cells i want are blank now and its not posted into Sheet2 the destination work sheet. @mike

Comment: Glad to help!  I've found Excel and VBA to be a blast!!

Comment: One additional comment, if you are going to be using a particular worksheet often in your code, you may want to consider doing something like:

    Dim WSS as worksheet and on the next line type:
    Set WSS = worksheets("Sheet1")

This will save you alot of typing.